# Scene Hierarchy with Translation, Rotation and Scale

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++17, entity-component-system, linear-algebra

This code represents an Entity Component that holds and manipulates an entity's local and world transforms, dealing with hierarchy and translation/rotation/scale transformations. The code is written in C++17.

This code was not built for performance or memory efficiency. It was built more as a way to learn how to support a scene hierarchy. By all means, you can point out ways where these two aspects could be improved, but the main reason for this code review is to ensure the mathematical and logical correctness of each operation.

**SceneComponent.hpp**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <Components/EntityComponent.hpp>

class SceneComponent : public EntityComponent
{
public:
    SceneComponent() = default;
    virtual ~SceneComponent();

    entt::entity GetParent() const { return m_parent; }
    std::vector<entt::entity> const& GetChildren() const { return m_children; }

    bool AttachTo(entt::entity parent);
    bool Detach();

    // Local transform
    inline glm::vec3 const& GetLocalTranslation() const { return m_localTransform.GetTranslation(); }
    inline glm::quat const& GetLocalRotation() const { return m_localTransform.GetRotation(); }
    inline glm::vec3 const& GetLocalScale() const { return m_localTransform.GetScale(); }
    inline glm::vec3 GetLocalEulerRotation() const { return m_localTransform.GetEulerRotation(); }
    inline glm::mat4 const& GetLocalMatrix() { return m_localTransform.GetMatrix(); }
    void SetLocalTranslation(glm::vec3 const& translation);
    void SetLocalScale(glm::vec3 const& scale);
    void SetLocalRotation(glm::quat const& rotation);
    void SetLocalEulerRotation(glm::vec3 const& eulerRotation);

    // World transform
    glm::vec3 const& GetWorldTranslation();
    glm::quat const& GetWorldRotation();
    glm::vec3 const& GetWorldScale();
    glm::vec3 GetWorldEulerRotation();
    glm::mat4 const& GetWorldMatrix();
    void SetWorldTranslation(glm::vec3 const& translation);
    void SetWorldScale(glm::vec3 const& scale);
    void SetWorldRotation(glm::quat const& rotation);
    void SetWorldEulerRotation(glm::vec3 const& eulerRotation);

private:
    struct Transform
    {
        Transform() = default;
        Transform(glm::vec3 const& translation, glm::quat const& rotation, glm::vec3 const& scale);

        // Getters
        inline glm::vec3 const& GetTranslation() const { return m_translation; }
        inline glm::quat const& GetRotation() const { return m_rotation; }
        inline glm::vec3 const& GetScale() const { return m_scale; }
        glm::vec3 GetEulerRotation() const;
        glm::mat4 const& GetMatrix();

        // Setters
        void SetTranslation(glm::vec3 const& translation);
        void SetScale(glm::vec3 const& scale);
        void SetRotation(glm::quat const& rotation);
        void SetEulerRotation(glm::vec3 const& eulerRotation);

        // Modifiers
        void Translate(glm::vec3 const& translation);
        void Scale(glm::vec3 const& scale);
        void Rotate(glm::vec3 const& eulerRotation);
        void Rotate(glm::quat const& rotation);

    private:
        void CalculateMatrix();

    private:
        glm::vec3 m_translation{ 0.0f };
        glm::quat m_rotation{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        glm::vec3 m_scale{ 1.0f };

        glm::mat4 m_matrix;
        bool m_isMatrixDirty = true;
    };

private:
    void InvalidateWorldTransformRecursively();
    void CalculateWorldTransform();
    bool IsDescendent(entt::entity const entity) const;

private:
    Transform m_localTransform;
    Transform m_worldTransform;
    bool m_isWorldTransformDirty = true;

    entt::entity m_parent = entt::null;
    std::vector<entt::entity> m_children;
};
```

**SceneComponent.cpp**

```cpp
#include <Components/SceneComponent.hpp>
#include <Systems/EntitySystem.hpp>

SceneComponent::~SceneComponent()
{
    Detach();

    for (entt::entity child : m_children)
    {
        SceneComponent& childScene = EntitySystem::GetInstance().GetComponent<SceneComponent>(child);
        childScene.Detach();
    }
}

bool SceneComponent::AttachTo(entt::entity parent)
{
    if (!EntitySystem::IsEntityValid(parent) || parent == m_parent)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (IsDescendent(parent))
    {
        return false; // Trying to attach to one of our descendents
    }

    if (EntitySystem::IsEntityValid(m_parent))
    {
        Detach();
    }
   
    SceneComponent& parentScene = EntitySystem::GetInstance().GetComponent<SceneComponent>(parent);
    parentScene.m_children.push_back(m_entity);
    m_parent = parent;

    SetWorldTranslation(GetLocalTranslation());
    SetWorldRotation(GetLocalRotation());
    SetWorldScale(GetLocalScale());

    return true;
}

bool SceneComponent::Detach()
{
    if (!EntitySystem::IsEntityValid(m_parent))
    {
        return false;
    }

    SetLocalTranslation(GetWorldTranslation());
    SetLocalRotation(GetWorldRotation());
    SetLocalScale(GetWorldScale());

    SceneComponent& parentScene = EntitySystem::GetInstance().GetComponent<SceneComponent>(m_parent);
    auto const childIt = std::find(parentScene.m_children.begin(), parentScene.m_children.end(), m_entity);
    if (childIt != parentScene.m_children.end())
    {
        parentScene.m_children.erase(childIt);
    }
    m_parent = entt::null;

    return true;
}

void SceneComponent::InvalidateWorldTransformRecursively()
{
    if (m_isWorldTransformDirty)
    {
        return; // Already dirty from another call
    }

    // Invalidate our world transform and our children's recursively
    m_isWorldTransformDirty = true;

    for (entt::entity child : m_children)
    {
        SceneComponent& childScene = EntitySystem::GetInstance().GetComponent<SceneComponent>(child);
        childScene.InvalidateWorldTransformRecursively();
    }
}

void SceneComponent::SetLocalTranslation(glm::vec3 const& translation) 
{
    m_localTransform.SetTranslation(translation);
    InvalidateWorldTransformRecursively();
}

void SceneComponent::SetLocalScale(glm::vec3 const& scale) 
{
    m_localTransform.SetScale(scale);
    InvalidateWorldTransformRecursively();
}

void SceneComponent::SetLocalRotation(glm::quat const& rotation) 
{
    m_localTransform.SetRotation(rotation);
    InvalidateWorldTransformRecursively();
}

void SceneComponent::SetLocalEulerRotation(glm::vec3 const& eulerRotation) 
{
    m_localTransform.SetEulerRotation(eulerRotation);
    InvalidateWorldTransformRecursively();
}

glm::mat4 const& SceneComponent::GetWorldMatrix()
{
    if (m_isWorldTransformDirty)
    {
        CalculateWorldTransform();
    }

    return m_worldTransform.GetMatrix();
}

glm::vec3 const& SceneComponent::GetWorldTranslation()
{
    if (m_isWorldTransformDirty)
    {
        CalculateWorldTransform();
    }

    return m_worldTransform.GetTranslation();
}

glm::quat const& SceneComponent::GetWorldRotation()
{
    if (m_isWorldTransformDirty)
    {
        CalculateWorldTransform();
    }

    return m_worldTransform.GetRotation();
}

glm::vec3 SceneComponent::GetWorldEulerRotation()
{
    if (m_isWorldTransformDirty)
    {
        CalculateWorldTransform();
    }

    return m_worldTransform.GetEulerRotation();
}

glm::vec3 const& SceneComponent::GetWorldScale()
{
    if (m_isWorldTransformDirty)
    {
        CalculateWorldTransform();
    }

    return m_worldTransform.GetScale();
}

void SceneComponent::SetWorldTranslation(glm::vec3 const& translation)
{
    if (EntitySystem::IsEntityValid(m_parent))
    {
        SceneComponent& parentScene = EntitySystem::GetInstance().GetComponent<SceneComponent>(m_parent);
        glm::mat4 const& parentWorldMatrix = parentScene.GetWorldMatrix();
        m_localTransform.SetTranslation(glm::inverse(parentWorldMatrix) * glm::vec4(translation, 1.0f));
    }
    else
    {
        m_localTransform.SetTranslation(translation);
    }

    InvalidateWorldTransformRecursively();
}

void SceneComponent::SetWorldScale(glm::vec3 const& scale)
{
    if (EntitySystem::IsEntityValid(m_parent))
    {
        SceneComponent& parentScene = EntitySystem::GetInstance().GetComponent<SceneComponent>(m_parent);
        m_localTransform.SetScale(scale / parentScene.GetWorldScale());
    }
    else
    {
        m_localTransform.SetScale(scale);
    }

    InvalidateWorldTransformRecursively();
}

void SceneComponent::SetWorldRotation(glm::quat const& rotation)
{
    if (EntitySystem::IsEntityValid(m_parent))
    {
        SceneComponent& parentScene = EntitySystem::GetInstance().GetComponent<SceneComponent>(m_parent);
        m_localTransform.SetRotation(glm::inverse(parentScene.GetWorldRotation()) * rotation);
    }
    else
    {
        m_localTransform.SetRotation(rotation);
    }

    InvalidateWorldTransformRecursively();
}

void SceneComponent::SetWorldEulerRotation(glm::vec3 const& eulerRotation)
{
    SetWorldRotation(glm::quat(eulerRotation));
}

void SceneComponent::CalculateWorldTransform()
{
    if (EntitySystem::IsEntityValid(m_parent))
    {
        SceneComponent& parentScene = EntitySystem::GetInstance().GetComponent<SceneComponent>(m_parent);
        m_worldTransform.SetTranslation(parentScene.GetWorldMatrix() * glm::vec4(m_localTransform.GetTranslation(), 1.0f));
        m_worldTransform.SetRotation(parentScene.GetWorldRotation() * m_localTransform.GetRotation());
        m_worldTransform.SetScale(parentScene.GetWorldScale() * m_localTransform.GetScale());
    }
    else
    {
        m_worldTransform = m_localTransform;
    }

    m_isWorldTransformDirty = false;
}

bool SceneComponent::IsDescendent(entt::entity const entity) const
{
    for (entt::entity child : m_children)
    {
        if (child == entity) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        SceneComponent const& childScene = EntitySystem::GetInstance().GetComponent<const SceneComponent>(child);
        if (childScene.IsDescendent(entity))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

SceneComponent::Transform::Transform(glm::vec3 const& translation, glm::quat const& rotation, glm::vec3 const& scale)
    : m_translation(translation)
    , m_rotation(rotation)
    , m_scale(scale)
{
}

glm::vec3 SceneComponent::Transform::GetEulerRotation() const
{
    // Returns pitch, yaw and roll
    return glm::eulerAngles(m_rotation);
}

glm::mat4 const& SceneComponent::Transform::GetMatrix()
{
    if (m_isMatrixDirty)
    {
        CalculateMatrix();
    }
    
    return m_matrix;
}

void SceneComponent::Transform::CalculateMatrix()
{
    glm::mat4 const translationMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), m_translation);
    glm::mat4 const rotationMatrix = glm::toMat4(m_rotation);
    glm::mat4 const scaleMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), m_scale);

    m_matrix = translationMatrix * rotationMatrix * scaleMatrix;

    m_isMatrixDirty = false;
}

void SceneComponent::Transform::SetTranslation(glm::vec3 const& translation)
{
    m_translation = translation;
    m_isMatrixDirty = true;
}

void SceneComponent::Transform::SetRotation(glm::quat const& rotation)
{
    m_rotation = rotation;
    m_isMatrixDirty = true;
}

void SceneComponent::Transform::SetScale(glm::vec3 const& scale)
{
    m_scale = scale;
    m_isMatrixDirty = true;
}

void SceneComponent::Transform::SetEulerRotation(glm::vec3 const& eulerRotation)
{
    m_rotation = glm::quat(eulerRotation);
    m_isMatrixDirty = true;
}

void SceneComponent::Transform::Translate(glm::vec3 const& translation)
{
    m_translation += translation;
    m_isMatrixDirty = true;
}

void SceneComponent::Transform::Rotate(glm::vec3 const& eulerRotation)
{
    // Applies euler angles in XYZ order
    Rotate(glm::quat(eulerRotation));
}

void SceneComponent::Transform::Rotate(glm::quat const& rotation)
{
    m_rotation = m_rotation * rotation;
    m_isMatrixDirty = true;
}

void SceneComponent::Transform::Scale(glm::vec3 const& scale)
{
    m_scale *= scale;
    m_isMatrixDirty = true;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you indicated which version of C++ you are using (c++11, c++14, c++17, c++20). Are you providing includes for the all the header files you are including?

Comment: @pacmaninbw Yes but I didn't provide the code for those headers because it didn't seem necessary for this code review, in my opinion. If anyone disagrees, I can add them. As for the C++ standard version, I'm using C++17.